# Problem with the use of break and else in conjunction with a for loop

Tags: python

in the book Kiusalaas, J. (2013). Numerical methods in engineering with Python 3. Cambridge University Press. page 10 the author has this line of code which does not work for me:

```py
list = ['Jack', 'Jill', 'Tim', 'Dave']
name = eval(input('Type a name: '))  # Python input prompt
for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] == name:
        print(name,'is number',i + 1,'on the list')
        break
else:
    print(name,'is not on the list')
```

I have this error: NameError: name "Tim" is not defined

I'm working locally using VS and a Virtual environment by anaconda

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. If that's in the book, get a new book.

Comment: and don't use weird `’` quotes.

Comment: You're using the wrong quote marks for all of your string literals.  You want just plain `'` or `"`, not the fancy typographer's quotes.

Comment: Perhaps more to the point: why are you using `eval()` - what problem do you need it to solve? The quotes are probably a copy/paste issue?

Comment: The book is about numerical recipes. I'll bet his example is for searching a list of numbers, not strings. But in that case you should use `int()` or `float()`, not `eval()`, but it won't get an error like this.

Comment: If the book really tells you to use `name = eval(input(’Type a name: ’))`, then it is a bad book and you should get another.

Comment: Why do you think this problem has anything to do with `break` and `else`? Didn't the error message tell you that the problem is on the input line, which has nothing to do with those statements?

Comment: [This book does indeed put that in its example](https://ia802301.us.archive.org/2/items/c-36_20211010/C36.pdf) - and the follow-up text does nothing to explain why it wants you to be able to enter Python code as input (e.g. `'Tim'` instead if just `Tim`). The advice of the others is sound - get a better book, this is teaching you bad practice. (further on, the book keeps going on about how using evaluation allows you to convert between types - I get the sense that the author misguidedly thought that might be a good way to explain the different types, but this book is particularly bad)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see you noticed the error message: `NameError: name "Tim" is not defined`. Before trying to ask a question, it is a good idea to try to *read* and *understand* the error message. According to your own understanding: *where in the code* did the error occur? What *kind* of error is it? *Why* does the error occur, according to the text of the error message? Do you understand what these things mean? (For example: do you understand what Python means by a "name", and what it means by "defined"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by others, and in the other answer, the problem is the use of `eval()`.

Your original code works if, instead of `Tim`, you try to enter `'Tim'` (after fixing the quotes), because Python will evaluate that into a string, which matches the value in the list.

However, this is exceedingly bad practice and should not be used unless there is really good reason to do so and the user of your script understands they are expected and able to enter working Python code.

The book goes on without much explanation of this, and seems to use it as a device to explain more about types. Also, the typographic use of quotes like these `’Input a: ’` instead of the regular ones like these `'Input a: '` shows that the author does not have the reader's interest at heart.

The real answer has to be: get a better book and warn others about using ["Kiusalaas, J. (2013). Numerical methods in engineering with Python 3. Cambridge University Press"](https://ia802301.us.archive.org/2/items/c-36_20211010/C36.pdf)

Perhaps it's fine for numerical methods, but it's lousy for teaching Python.

Note: perhaps the June 2014 online edition is better, but I'd spend my money on something else. Besides, who teaches programming in 2022 on a modern language with an 8-9 years old book?

Comment: From the foreword: "The book is based on Numerical Methods in Engineering with
Python, which used Python 2. Apart from the migration from Python
2 to Python 3" This is already a huge red flag - although not one that the author can really avoid raising. Everything that was originally written for 2.x - and therefore *had to be updated* for 3.x - is suspect, because there was a lot of really bad advice going around about how to do it (due to a refusal to acknowledge that 2.x's mistakes were mistakes) and a lot of lazy translation (due to strong backwards compatibility requirements).

Comment: You're absolutely right - with something as major as a full version number upgrade of Python from 2 to 3, never mind the continued development of excellent libraries that support numerical methods, and the fact that they all went through the same version transition, the only sensible course of action would have been a *rewrite*, not just an *update*.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `eval`:

```
list = ['Jack', 'Jill', 'Tim', 'Dave']
name = input('Type a name: ')
for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] == name:
        print(name,'is number',i + 1,'on the list')
        break
else:
    print(name,'is not on the list')

# Type a name: Tim
# Tim is number 3 on the list
```